# How to prevent division when using variables separated by a slash in CSS property values

Tags: css, sass

When I try to use variables for the font-size and line-height portion of the font shorthand property, Sass performs division instead of separating the two values with a slash.

```
@mixin test($fontsize, $lineheight) { font: $fontsize/$lineheight sans-serif; }

#my-font { @include test(14px, 20px); }
```

This currently outputs:

```
#my-font { font: 0.7 sans-serif; }
```

How can I tell Sass to stop doing division?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use the [`#{}` interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) notation to treat your variables as strings.  Since Sass cannot perform arithmetic on strings, the `/` gets treated as a literal slash instead of the division operator:

```
@mixin test($fontsize, $lineheight) {
    font: #{$fontsize}/#{$lineheight} sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

BoltClock's answer does work in most cases, however if the variable `$fontsize` is a function, for example `$fontsize: rem-calc(10px)`, it will output as a string.

A more bulletproof way is to interpolate the slash:

```
@mixin test($fontsize, $lineheight) {
    font: $fontsize #{"/"} $lineheight sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: If `$fontsize` is being set to a literal string of `rem-calc(10px)` instead of being evaluated, what you're suggesting is not going to change a thing.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27588136/using-a-function-in-sass-is-returning-the-string-containing-the-name-of-the-func

Comment: It isn't a string literal. A string literal would be:
`$fontsize: "rem-calc(10px)"
I'm literally using this code right now to cover the scenario I have highlighted. Try your/the accepted answer when $fontsize is set to a function. You will find it doesn't work.

Comment: Also I don't see the relevance of your link. Please elaborate.

Comment: Looks like both examples handle values from functions correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/vpL6mp3g/

Comment: I don't understand this answer at all. Is this not what is expected?: https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/2fd99ac03449bb4a8b768dff9e19103f