# LESS CSS pass string to mixin

Tags: css, less, mixins

I am trying to pass something like this to a mixin

```
.myMixin(Pdcbs/sjdhc+jdjhdf);
```

This fails when compiling, syntax error

I tried wrapping the string in quotes but in the output I see my parameter get outputted like

```
background: ...@{paramName}
```

I tried ~"stringhere"... I been on this for hours now Please point me to the right direction, thanks

Comment: ~"string" is used to pass invalid CSS. Are you sure that it's not being passed? It might be that Pdcbs/sjdhc+jdjhdf isn't doing what you think it is supposed to.

Comment: If you're using SASS then check this question out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988944/scss-font-shorthand

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not quite certain what you are seeking to have as output, but this:

```
.mixin(@paramName) {
  background: ~"...@{paramName}";
}

.mixin("Pdcbs/sjdhc+jdjhdf");
```

Produces this for me:

```
background: ...Pdcbs/sjdhc+jdjhdf;
```

Comment: this is what I am looking for. I saw the the escape method on Less site I thought it was used differently, thanks

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much.