# SASS: expression or plain CSS slash?

Tags: css, parsing, compiler-construction, sass

I am currently implementing a SASS compiler in Go - [c6](https://github.com/c9s/c6), and I found some strange behaviors of the Ruby SASS compiler when I was writing the expression parser and evaluator.

The SASS reference mentioned the plain CSS '/' and the SASS division expression here:
http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#division-and-slash

The design is to make SASS compatible with native CSS syntax like this:

```
font: 10px/8px;             // Plain CSS, no division. looks fine.
font: 10px/8px + 3px;       // Expression
font: (10px/8px);           // Expression
```

The above seems OK, but if you write:

```
.foo {
  $a: 10px/8px;
  font: $a;
}
```

And the above will be compiled to:

```
.foo {
   font: 1.25; }
```

The normal expression in the following SASS will always be expression without parenthesis:

```
.foo {
  padding: 2px+2px;
  padding: 2px*3;
}
```

Outputs:

```
.foo {
  padding: 4px;
  padding: 6px; }
```

However the following SASS produces different results:

```
.foo {
  padding: 2px-1px;
  padding: 2px - 1px;
}
```

And the above will be compiled to:

```
.foo {
  padding: 2px-1px; // treated as ident instead of expression
  padding: 1px; }
```

And it seems the division operator is the only exception for property value, which makes the syntax inconsistent and ambiguous. (actually there are so many ambiguous grammars in the SASS specification...)

So here is the question:

1. How can I make the expression syntax consistent and avoid the implicitly behavior between plain CSS '/' and divide operator? (if we don't consider the compatibility of SASS)
2. and what will you do?

Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is for solving technical problems.  "I don't know what syntax I should use for my imaginary language" does not count as a technical problem, this is a purely opinionated question.

Comment: Might be better on programmers.se

Comment: @cimmanon: There is no imaginary language here. The OP is implementing a Sass compiler and is asking how to handle a specific edge case. The answer, it would seem, is that there is no consistent way to do so.

Comment: @BoltClock The OP states "if we don't consider the compatibility of SASS", so it wouldn't exactly be a Sass compiler.

Comment: @BoltClock If the OP wants to know how to prevent division from occurring in Sass, then this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988944/scss-font-shorthand (which, ironically, you answered :p)

Comment: @cimmanon: I DON'T EVEN REMEMBER ANSWERING THAT! Instant close.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known syntax ambiguity. [Some workarounds](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/667) have previously been discussed on the [SASS github page](https://github.com/sass/sass). But further from there I can't really suggest anything better :(

What would I do? It's not particularly appropriate for StackOverflow, but let me take the `font: 10px/8px` example that you give. You make use of a variable, so I assume it's a style value that you intend to use more than once. The value itself (`10px/8px`) seems fairly explicitly intended for use with `font`, so I would take a slightly different approach, and use a `%silent-class`:

```
%font {
    font: 10px/8px;
}

.foo {
    @extend %font;
    // more styling here
}
.bar {
    @extend %font;
    // etc
}
```

This compiles correctly, sans division:

```
.foo {
    font: 10px/8px;
}
.bar {
    font: 10px/8px;
}
```

As for the `padding` example, I think that's just poor consistency. Hopefully they'll correct that in the near future. If it hasn't already been done, it wouldn't be a bad idea for you to [submit an issue](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues) if you feel strongly about it, see what they say.