# Ember serve thinks "/" is a division in shorthand background property

Tags: ember.js, sass, ember-cli

I have below code in my scss file.

```
.logo {
  background: url('../images/logo-web.svg') no-repeat -15px -453px / 235px 630px transparent;
}
```

When ember compile scss compiler thinks it's a division and do the calculation. This happens when I use ember serve only. Due to that issue syntax for the background is going to be wrong.

And this is what browser reads.

```
background: url("../images/logo-web.svg") no-repeat -15px -1.92766 630px transparent;
```

Above code will compile without any issues if I use sass compiler directly. This issue only happens when I compile using `ember serve`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988944/how-to-prevent-division-when-using-variables-separated-by-a-slash-in-css-propert.  Note that I cannot reproduce this using the provided code with just Sass.

Comment: Using only sass this code work perfectly. Problem is with Ember compiler.

Comment: @cimmanon, I went through the link you shared. They way described in the second answer worked for me `#{"/"}`. But I don't think its the best way to solve my issue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the ember compiler. Ember doesn't even support SASS out of the box. I'm guessing you are using the ember-cli-sass addon, which compiles your sass using libsass. When you say you are using the sass compiler directly, are you using libsass, or some other sass compiler?

Answer (score 1):

So this is likely this bug in the libsass compiler, which has already been fixed: https://github.com/sass/libsass/issues/1642

I suggest you update your ember-cli-sass addon to the latest version and then:

1. delete node modules
2. npm cache clear
3. npm install

Comment: Hey @Gaurav, thanx for the reply and the suggestion. I did what you have specified here and still having the same issue. I went through node modules folder and confirmed that all the packages are up to date. But I still have the problem...

Comment: Well you may want to report an issue in libsass.